# Using save() inside behavior which is attached to ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2

I have `ActiveRecord` instance with bunch of behaviors attached.

Inside one of them related models get updated (besides `owner`). Using `updateAttributes()` is OK, but I want to trigger few behaviors for updating related models, for example `TimestampBehavior`, `BlameableBehavior`, `LogBehavior` (custom one).

If we call `save()` inside model recursion can occur, and sometimes some behaviors must be excluded.

I came up with following solution, but it fails when attaching behaviors back.

```
$detachedBehaviors = $this->getDetachedBehaviors();

foreach ($model->behaviors as $key => $behavior) {
    if (in_array($behavior::className(), $detachedBehaviors)) {
        $model->detachBehavior($key);
    }
}

$model->save(false, [$this->attribute]);

$model->attachBehaviors($detachedBehaviors);
```

Maybe there is better way of doing that?

I see another alternative:

1. Somehow manually trigger needed events of needed behaviors.
2. Use `updateAttributes()` instead of calling `save()`.

Actually I don't want to bind this logic to specific behavior and made this available for any behavior which is more flexible. So I guess it will be another behavior.